# How to find data based on Many To Many relationship in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

I have a Many To Many relationship between User Model & Wallet Model:

`Wallet.php`:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

And `User.php`:

```
public function wallets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class);
    }
```

And I have these three tables related to Wallets:

Table `wallets`:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('wallets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->tinyInteger('is_active');
            $table->tinyInteger('is_cachable');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Table `user_wallet`:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_wallet', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('usr_id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wallet_id');
            $table->foreign('wallet_id')->references('id')->on('wallets');
            $table->integer('balance');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And table `user_wallet_transactions`:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_wallet_transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('usr_id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wallet_id');
            $table->foreign('wallet_id')->references('id')->on('wallets');
            $table->string('amount');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Now I need to show wallets of a single user. So at the `users.index` Blade, I added this:

```
<a href="{{ route('user.wallet', $user->usr_id) }}" class="fa fa-wallet text-dark"></a>
```

And send the user data to Controller like this:

```
public function index(User $user)
    {
        // retrieve user_wallet information
        return view('admin.wallets.user.index', compact(['user']));
    }
```

But I don't know how to retrieve `user_wallet` information at this Method.

So how to get data from `user_wallet` in this situation.

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is  accept `param` as `$id`

```
public function index($id)
```

then

```
User::with('wallets')->has('wallets')->find($id);
```

Comment: So u mean I should be removing `User $user` as parameter of this method?

Comment: if you need both user and wallet detail then its good i think .or else you can do $wallet=$user->wallets; this will return wallets detail seperately.There might be other solution but  i use most of the time this approach