# Laravel 5.8: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column error in Many To Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

I have a Many To Many relationship between User Model & Wallet Model:

`Wallet.php`:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

And `User.php`:

```
public function wallets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class);
    }
```

And I want to get wallet list of a single user like this:

```
@forelse($user->wallets as $wallet)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $wallet->id }}</td>
</tr>
@empty
<td colspan="5" class="text-center">No wallet exist</td>
@endforelse
```

But I get this error somehow:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'user_wallet.user_usr_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `wallets`.*,
> `user_wallet`.`user_usr_id` as `pivot_user_usr_id`,
> `user_wallet`.`wallet_id` as `pivot_wallet_id` from `wallets` inner
> join `user_wallet` on `wallets`.`id` = `user_wallet`.`wallet_id` where
> `user_wallet`.`user_usr_id` = 373)

However the wallet within this user id exists already at `user_wallet` table:

[image]

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Mentioning pivot table in relationship

```
public function users()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id');
}
```

and

```
public function wallets()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','wallet_id','user_id');
}
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Still `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column`

Comment: That was great, thank u, but how to get the `wallet` name based on the `wallet_id`

Comment: Wallet name is stored at `wallets` table. I had put the information of Migrations in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372299/how-to-find-data-based-on-many-to-many-relationship-in-laravel-5-8

Comment: @loctoj since its seperate issue .so i have updated in that question

Comment: Hey dude, I wonder if both belongsToMany relationships defined with with the same keys in the same order ie 'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id' are correct or not?

Comment: @loctoj just reverse it based on current model if its error.i usaully not using since i follow laravel naming conventio.let me know if that issue so i can update post

Comment: if that causing then  public function wallets()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','wallet_id','user_id');
}

Comment: Yeah I think it should be updated for other people not to get confused.

Comment: But wait! I tested it and wallet details of a user who has a record on `user_wallet` table does not appear when changing keys of `wallets()` function in User model ! Seems like the first answer was correct. It looks strange somehow.

Comment: @loctoj if you want only those record which has walet or visa versa then you have to use  has. i have tested it .so no more issues regarding relationship

Comment: @loctoj to retrieve only  those record who has wallet then your query should add has('relationname')

Comment: Plz checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375097/laravel-many-to-many-relationship-does-not-show-data

Comment: @loctoj check my updated answer and delete that new post

Comment: Thank u brother. God saves you <3